# Interpretation of the conformal symmetry of Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Consider the linear Schrodinger equation
$$
\begin{cases}
i\partial_t u + \Delta u =0,\\
u|_{t=0}=u_0,
\end{cases},
t\in\mathbb R,x\in \mathbb R^n, u\in \mathbb C.
$$
If $v$ is a solution to the problem, then so is
$$
u(t,x):=\frac{1}{(1+t)^{n/2}} v(t/(1+t), x/(1+t)) \exp\left(i\frac{|x|}{4(1+t)}\right).
$$

My question is: do we have a nice physical interpretation of this result? How do people come up with this at the first place?

NOTE: Of course we can prove dissipation of wave packets by this symmetry, but I wish to have something more specific: this formula certainly provides much more information than the general rate of spread of probability amplitudes.